# What should I do with the sympy to get a 'normal' result for the integral?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

My exercise is to integrate some functions with sympy. The first integral is (I'm going to add it on images, because I can't use latex here, but you can also see it in the code):
[image]
with
[image]
And a is a real constant.

This is my code:

```
%pylab inline
from sympy import *
init_printing()
v, a = symbols('v, a', real=True, nonzero=True)
f = sqrt(2/pi)*(v**2*exp((-v**2)/(2*a**2)))/(a**3)
print(integrate(v*f, (v, 0, oo)))
```

(Note: I only used print to get this copiable result)
But the result is really ugly:

```
Piecewise((2*sqrt(2)*a/sqrt(pi), Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(a)**(-2), oo)) < pi/2), (Integral(sqrt(2)*v**3*exp(-v**2/(2*a**2))/(sqrt(pi)*a**3), (v, 0, oo)), True))
```

But with the modification

```
v, a = symbols('v, a', positive=True)
```

or

```
v, a = symbols('v, a', negative=True)
```

The result is

```
2*sqrt(2)*a/sqrt(pi)
```

But as far as I know, the only real number with the property of being neither negative nor positive is the zero - and that should be excluded with the 'nonzero=True' part.

**Q:** What can I do with my first code to get 'nice' result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current development version the output is less ugly:

```
Piecewise((2*sqrt(2)*a/sqrt(pi), pi/2 > 2*Abs(arg(a))), (Integral(sqrt(2)*v**3*exp(-v**2/(2*a**2))/(sqrt(pi)*a**3), (v, 0, oo)), True))
```

Still a room for improvement, though. I suggest raising an issue at [issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues).

#### Workarounds

The reason for Piecewise is that SymPy is not sure that the integral converges if the condition `pi/2 > 2*Abs(arg(a))` does not hold. Since you know that it does converge in your context, you can tell SymPy not to bother with the convergence condition, by setting `conds="none"`:

```
>>> integrate(v*f, (v, 0, oo), conds="none") 
2*sqrt(2)*a/sqrt(pi)
```

Alternatively, using assumptions: setting "positive" assumption on `a` is enough. You can do this for the integration step, by temporarily swapping `a` with a positive symbol.

```
>>> apos = symbols('apos', positive=True)
>>> integrate(v*f.subs(a, apos), (v, 0, oo)).subs(apos, a)
2*sqrt(2)*a/sqrt(pi)
```

This allows `a` to remain as it was in the larger context of computation.

#### Explanation

Here's an informal explanation of why the assumption set (real and nonzero) has less impact than either (positive) or (negative).

1. A certain thing can be done if `a` is known to be positive, and it results in nice output.
2. Another thing can be done if `a` is known to be negative, and it results in nice output.

Given that `a` is real and nonzero, SymPy asks: can I do the first thing? No, because there is no guarantee that `a` is positive. Then it asks: can I do the second thing? No, because there is no guarantee that `a` is negative. So, neither gets done.

> The core issue is that there are limitations to using Python logic to do symbolic logic. In Python logic, everything must be evaluated down to a single truth value. In symbolic logic, expressions may have unknown truth values. Another example of this is the law of the excluded middle. Python does not know that "stuff or not stuff" is always True without first evaluating "stuff". Symbolic logic can know this, even if the truth value of "stuff" is unknown. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Assumptions-history

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Did you use any restriction (like real=True) to get the first result? I was also thinking about replacing the a with a positive variable, but the second integral has an abs(a) in it, and I think that method would not give abs(a) after the replacement, but just a.

Comment: I did, but the result is the same without any assumptions. What made the difference is that I used the dev version ([cloned from github](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/#download)), in which a [recent PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/14092) simplified the convergence condition. The condition is still there, it just looks less ugly.

Comment: The bottom line is, the square root of `a**2` gets taken, and it complicates the matters that the sign of `a` is unknown. If it's known, the root evaluates to `a` or `-a`, simplifying things. I expanded on this point a bit.

Comment: Probably, `conds="none"` is the best option for your use case.